# error: not found: value GitVersioning enablePlugins(GitVersioning)

Tags: git, scala, apache-spark, github, sbt

When try copying my project sbt file in my local Intellij project then i am getting error related to GitVersioning.
I have also done with adding remote to origin .

```
enablePlugins(GitVersioning)
assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}_${scalaVersion.value}-${version.value}.jar"
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  //case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Below is the error which i am getting when i compile the code.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/Z001T1J/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.7 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_291)
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/Z001T1J/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /Users/Z001T1J/Documents/GitClone/flcDprSmryLoadPerth/project
/Users/Z001T1J/Documents/GitClone/flcDprSmryLoadPerth/build.sbt:67: error: not found: value GitVersioning
enablePlugins(GitVersioning)
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Comment: You talk about copying some files, did you copy the `plugins.sbt` file as well?

Comment: @GaëlJ I have just copied the build.sbt file. i have not copied any `plugins.sbt` file, i dont know where to find that file or how to copy that file.

Answer (score 1):

copying the assembly.sbt file solved the issue.